# Installing LS-PrePost on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I'd like to install LS-PrePost on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
The most recent version of LS-PrePost (4.6) isn't available packed for Ubuntu, but version 4.5 has a version that was packed for Ubuntu 16. Download is here: ftp://ftp.lstc.com/outgoing/lsprepost/4.5/linux64/

I downloaded and unpacked the .tgz, followed the readme directions and I can't get it to run.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it futile to try making something compiled for 16 work on 18?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly did you do, and what happens when you try to run it? At a minimum, it looks like you will need to deal with the fact that it wants `libpng12` whereas 18.04 provides `libpng16`

Comment: Thank you for the information - I installed libpng12 and was still getting several errors, but after reading the reply below I'm attempting to go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way is to download and unpack modern 4.6 version suited for SLES 12 ([`lsprepost-4.6-sles12-19Feb2019.tgz`](ftp://ftp.lstc.com/outgoing/lsprepost/4.6/linux64/lsprepost-4.6-sles12-19Feb2019.tgz)).

I have just tested it on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

---

For previous 4.5 version you need to do many manual steps (see revisions of this answer if you really need it).

Comment: Thank you N0rbert! I had started down the path of trying to make 4.5 work, but if 4.6 will work easier that is preferable.

I downloaded and unpacked 4.6-sles12 to /home/usr
I edited the lspp46 file as per the readme file.

I can now run "lsrun" and it executes as expected, however lsprepost doesn't seem to do anything. Whether I execute it via right click/run or try to run it through the terminal. 

Any further insight on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: This is the lspp46 script, all I changed was the directory name:
`#!/bin/bash

# modify the following line for your directory name
DN="/home/skeeter/lsprepost4.6_sles12"
export LSPP_HELPDIR=$DN/resource/HelpDocument
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DN/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

$DN/lsprepost $*`

Comment: Quick update for future reference - I deleted everything i had done, started from scratch, unpacked the sles12 version linked above again. Edited the lspp46 script as described in the readme and executed it from the terminal - wala, it worked. Thanks again!